# Check if row exists in SQLite with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to know if a row exists already in one of my tables, in this case `coll`. In order to do this I played around with SQLite in the shell a little and stumbled upon `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM coll WHERE ceeb="1234")`. In SQLite this works perfectly and it returns either a `0` or a `1`-- which is exactly what I wanted. So, with code in hand, I wrote up a quick Python script to see if I could get this to work for me before sticking it into my program. This is what I came up with:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('stu.db')
c = conn.cursor()

sceeb = int(raw_input(":> "))

ceeb_exists = c.execute('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM coll WHERE ceeb="%d" LIMIT 1)' % sceeb)

print ceeb_exists
```

Instead of assigning `ceeb_exists`a `1` or a `0` it gives me an output that looks like `<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x01DF6860>`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The execution of a query *always* results in 0 or more rows. You'd need to fetch those rows; a `SELECT EXISTS` query results in 1 row, so you'd need to fetch that row.

Rows always consist of 1 or more columns, here you get one, so you could use tuple assignment (note the `,` comma after `ceeb_exists`):

```
c.execute('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM coll WHERE ceeb="%d" LIMIT 1)' % sceeb)
ceeb_exists, = c.fetchone()
```

However, using an `EXISTS` query is a bit redundant here; you could just test if there is *any* row returned. You should also use *query parameters* to avoid a SQL injection attack (you are asking a user to give you the `ceeb` value, so that is easily hijacked):

```
c.execute('SELECT 1 FROM coll WHERE ceeb=? LIMIT 1', (sceeb,))
ceeb_exists = c.fetchone() is not None
```

`cursor.fetchone()` returns `None` if there is no row available to fetch, the `is not None` test turns that into `True` or `False`.

Comment: Works wonders, thanks! And this is just for my own use at work, so I don't need to worry about injection attacks.

Comment: @IanPringle: it is always good practice to use query parameters; it also makes it possible for the database driver to create prepared execution plan for that query and re-use it for different parameters, for example.

Answer (score 1):

`.executes()` returns a cursor object as you can see. 
In order to print the results of the query you need to iterate over it:

```
for result in exists:
    print result
```

Comment: This worked, but it required a little cleaning up of the data with regex or something to make it usable. But I did not know that about cursor objects, thanks!